# How to split a Mesh with random_selection

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to split a mesh with random_selection.

My question is: How do I make sure that the "random_selection", selects the faces in a mesh to exact no. as specified by percentage. for example: A 10*10 Mesh contains 100 faces, so 50% of random selection should select exactly 50 faces, but in reality it selects sometime 48, 51, and so on. 
here is my noob Code:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

myob = bpy.ops.mesh
m = bpy.context.object
me = m.data

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(m.data)
face = bm.faces
myob.select_random(percent=50.0)
if len(bm.faces.select) == 100*50/100:
    bpy.ops.mesh.split
else:
    Pass
```

I am newbei in Python scripting and blender APIs does not helping me in understanding it clearly on 'How to get access the face information in a mesh'

```
len(bm.faces) # Will tell the total faces in a mesh
bm.faces[i].select = true # Will select one face at a time
```

but, how do I know, How much faces are exactly been selected. Any suggestion:

Here is some code I tried:

```
for i in range(100):
    if bm.faces[i].select:
        fac.append(bm.faces[i])
        count += 1        
if len(fac) < 50:
    for i in range(50):
        if bm.faces[i].select == False:
            bm.faces[i].select = True
            fac.append(bm.faces[i])
        continue
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(m.data, True)        
elif len(fac) > 50:
    print (count - 50, "are extra faces." )
    for j in range(100):
        if bm.faces[j].select == True:
            bm.faces[j].select = False
            if bm.faces[j] in fac:
                del fac[j] #problem here
        continue    
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(m.data, True)
else:
    print ("Exactly 50 faces are selected")
```

I somehow manage to select missing faces to make them 50 faces, but how do I deselect and remove them from list of selected faces.

Comment: Is this different from your other 'splitting' question?

Comment: If I get the answer of this question then this will help me solving my previous question. I thought to just break down my questions into small parts, so that I can easily get the response from genies.

Comment: Yes, random value will give expected value and not the exact. That's why I thought to iterate as long as it will select exactly 50 faces. <br/> I want to select exact portion specified by a percent and split it to make new mesh. I am also open to any other alternative other than random. The newly created meshes should not contain a chunk of consecutive  faces.

Comment: A couple of things, can the mesh simply be created rather than using an existing mesh.  To make sure you don't get large islands split down into smaller chunks, eg a 10 by 10 can be split into 25  lots of 2x2 meshes each with 2 randomly selected faces (for 50%)

Comment: Yes, to create a mesh with any method is acceptable. What I want to achieve is to split the mesh. I am trying to create a pattern of different objects that will be face duplicated on these split meshes. The pattern should be completed mixed in N by N mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy
import bmesh
myob = bpy.ops.mesh
m = bpy.context.object # objects in the context
me = m.data
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE') #unselect all

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(m.data) # bmesh represention of context data
face = bm.faces     #face coordinates and their indices

def selection(p):
    count = 0
    fac = [] # selected faces are stored in a list
    total = 0
    myob.select_random(percent=p) # random selection
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(m.data, True) #update to see selection in viewport

 #make sure to iterate each face in a mesh

    for i in range(len(bm.faces)):
        if bm.faces[i].select:
        fac.append(bm.faces[i])
        count += 1        
    total += 1    
    #print ("total faces in the object are: ",total)

    percent = round(total * p / 100)

    if count < percent:
    #print (50 - count, "faces are missing.")
        diff  = int(percent - count)
        cont = 0
        ind = 0

        while (cont < diff):
            if bm.faces[ind].select == False:
                bm.faces[ind].select = True
                #fac.append(bm.faces[i])
                cont += 1
            else:    
                ind += 1
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(m.data, True)
        print ("%s"%p, "percent of faces, in total",percent, "are selected")

     elif count > percent:
         #print (count - 50, "are extra faces." )
         diff = int(count - percent) #example 5, the next loop should remove these 5 selections from the mesh
         cont = 0
         ind = 0

         while (cont < diff):
             if bm.faces[ind].select == True:
                 bm.faces[ind].select = False
                 cont += 1
             else:
                 ind += 1   
         bmesh.update_edit_mesh(m.data, True)
         print ("%s"%p, "percent of faces, in total",percent, "are selected")
     else:
         print ("%s"%p, "percent of faces, in total",percent, "are selected")

 selection(40)
```

This chunk of code will select exact faces as specified by the percentage.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another take, that randomly selects from all faces using [`randint(0, len(faces))`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.randint) pops the selected face from faces list and adds to selected until the desired length is achieved.

```
import bpy
from random import randint

context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
mesh = obj.data
# check that percent is between 0 and 100.
percent = 40
# test code to run in edit mode
import bmesh
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
# deselect all
for f in bm.faces:
    f.select = False
# amount that need to be selected (to nearest int)
select_count = int(percent * len(bm.faces) / 100)
# unselected 
faces = [f for f in bm.faces] # could use f.index
# selected
selected = []

while len(selected) < select_count:
    # choose randomly from faces
    i = randint(0, len(faces) - 1)

    # pop and select
    f = faces.pop(i)
    f.select = True
    selected.append(f) # or use f.index
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)

print("Selected %d of %d" % (len(selected), len(bm.faces)))
```

Comment: You might try str.format() instead of the old formatting at the end... http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452357/6655092

Comment: Your code is just half of the length of my version. I do not understand, why did you use Swap. If I omit swap line and insert 'i' in f = faces.pop(i). This will do still the same.

Comment: Yes you're right... forgot about indexing pop instead of swap n pop, will edit accordingly,